# How to use UDFs with pandas on pyspark groupby?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-koalas

I am struggling to use pandas UDFs on pandas on pyspark. Can you please help me understand how this is to be achieved? Below is my attempt:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark import pandas as ps
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = ps.DataFrame({'A': 'a a b'.split(),
                   'B': [1, 2, 3],
                   'C': [4, 6, 5]}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
@pandas_udf('float')
def agg_a(x):
    return (x**2).mean()
@pandas_udf('float')
def agg_b(x):
    return x.mean()
spark.udf.register('agg_a_',agg_a)
spark.udf.register('agg_b_',agg_b)
df_means = df.groupby('A')
dfout=df_means.agg({'B':'agg_a_','C':'agg_b_'})
```

This results in an exception I am struggling to understand:

```
AnalysisException: expression 'B' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
Aggregate [__index_level_0__#14], [__index_level_0__#14, agg_a_(B#2L) AS B#15, agg_b_(C#3L) AS C#16]
+- Project [A#1 AS __index_level_0__#14, A#1, B#2L, C#3L]
   +- Project [__index_level_0__#0L, A#1, B#2L, C#3L, monotonically_increasing_id() AS __natural_order__#8L]
      +- LogicalRDD [__index_level_0__#0L, A#1, B#2L, C#3L], false
```

I tried using `udf` instead of `pandas_udf` but, that too fails with same exception

I tried using groupby with UDFs only on one column as well but that too fails:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark import pandas as ps
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = ps.DataFrame({'A': 'a a b'.split(),
                   'B': [1, 2, 3],
                   'C': [4, 6, 5]}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
@udf('float')
def agg_a(x):
    return (x**2).mean()
@udf('float')
def agg_b(x):
    return x.mean()
spark.udf.register('agg_a_',agg_a)
spark.udf.register('agg_b_',agg_b)
df_means = df.groupby('A')['B']
dfout=df_means.agg('agg_a_')
```

output:

```
PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.groupby.GroupBy.agg()` is not implemented yet.
```

This is not true I guess. I can use groupby if I don't use UDFs and use already defined functions like 'min', 'max'.

I tried using without specifying different UDFs columnwise and that too failed:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark import pandas as ps
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = ps.DataFrame({'A': 'a a b'.split(),
                   'B': [1, 2, 3],
                   'C': [4, 6, 5]}, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
@udf('float')
def agg_a(x):
    return (x**2).mean()
@udf('float')
def agg_b(x):
    return x.mean()
spark.udf.register('agg_a_',agg_a)
spark.udf.register('agg_b_',agg_b)
df_means = df.groupby('A')
dfout=df_means.agg('agg_a_')
```

output:

```
AnalysisException: expression 'B' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
Aggregate [__index_level_0__#14], [__index_level_0__#14, agg_a_(B#2L) AS B#15, agg_a_(C#3L) AS C#16]
+- Project [A#1 AS __index_level_0__#14, A#1, B#2L, C#3L]
   +- Project [__index_level_0__#0L, A#1, B#2L, C#3L, monotonically_increasing_id() AS __natural_order__#8L]
      +- LogicalRDD [__index_level_0__#0L, A#1, B#2L, C#3L], false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`GroupedData.agg` documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg), you need to define your `pandas_udf` with `PandasUDFType`. And if you need an aggregation then it would be `PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG`.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf('float', PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def agg_a(x):
    return (x**2).mean()

@pandas_udf('float', PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def agg_b(x):
    return x.mean()

spark.udf.register('agg_a_',agg_a)
spark.udf.register('agg_b_',agg_b)

df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'agg_a_','C':'agg_b_'}).show()

# +---+---------+---------+
# |  A|agg_a_(B)|agg_b_(C)|
# +---+---------+---------+
# |  b|      9.0|      5.0|
# |  a|      2.5|      5.0|
# +---+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Is registering these functions necessary?

Comment: No if you trigger it differently `df.groupby('A').agg(agg_a('B'), agg_b('C')).show()`

Comment: Can you try running it that way? I'm getting ```ValueError: aggs must be a dict mapping from column name to aggregate functions (string or list of strings).```

Comment: Feel free to join [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238666/room-for-pltc-and-milominderbinder) with me