# how to use @pandas_udf of pyspark for groupby.agg

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the pandas API on Spark. And I am using the `groupby.agg` operation. I found [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69731942/how-to-use-udfs-with-pandas-on-pyspark-groupby), but the solution does not work for me. I also checked the official docs. But the docs does not provide enough examples.

Here is my sample data:

|  | L_SHIPMODE | O_ORDERPRIORITY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | MAIL | 2 -HIGH |
| 1 | SHIP | 1 -URGENT |

And I just want to groupby `L_SHIPMODE` and count on `O_ORDERPRIORITY` by the following udf:

```py
@pandas_udf(IntegerType())
def g1(x):
  return ((x == "1-URGENT") | (x == "2-HIGH")).sum()

@pandas_udf(IntegerType())
def g2(x):
  return ((x != "1-URGENT") & (x != "2-HIGH")).sum()

# tryied register, but it seems this is not the problem
# spark.udf.register('g1_udf', g1)
# spark.udf.register('g2_udf', g2)

total = jn.groupby("L_SHIPMODE", as_index=False)["O_ORDERPRIORITY"].agg({"O_ORDERPRIORITY": [g1, g2]})
```

I got:

`ValueError: aggs must be a dict mapping from column name to aggregate functions (string or list of strings).`

Are there any detailed examples on how to use UDF on `groupby.agg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can avoid using udfs altogether if you create some new columns before your groupby (using a sample dataframe similar to yours):

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps

jn = ps.DataFrame({
    'L_SHIPMODE': ['MAIL']*4+['SHIP']*4,
    'O_ORDERPRIORITY': [
        '1 -URGENT', '2 -HIGH', '3 -OTHER', '4 -OTHER',
        '3 -OTHER', '4 -OTHER', '3 -OTHER', '4 -OTHER',
    ]
})

    L_SHIPMODE  O_ORDERPRIORITY
0   MAIL    1 -URGENT
1   MAIL    2 -HIGH
2   MAIL    3 -OTHER
3   MAIL    4 -OTHER
4   SHIP    3 -OTHER
5   SHIP    4 -OTHER
6   SHIP    3 -OTHER
7   SHIP    4 -OTHER

jn['1_OR_2'] = jn['O_ORDERPRIORITY'].isin(["1 -URGENT", "2 -HIGH"]).astype('long')
jn['not_1_OR_2'] = (~jn['O_ORDERPRIORITY'].isin(["1 -URGENT", "2 -HIGH"])).astype('long')

jn.groupby(
    'L_SHIPMODE'
).agg({
    '1_OR_2': 'sum',
    'not_1_OR_2': 'sum'
})
```

Result:

```
    1_OR_2  not_1_OR_2
L_SHIPMODE      
MAIL    2   2
SHIP    0   4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is indeed a solution. But I am using the pyspark.pandas API and it seems this solution is pyspark.sql. Spark cannot find `.withColumn`.

Comment: oh my mistake, thanks for pointing that out. let me see if i can get a working `pyspark.pandas` solution

Comment: I've updated my answer – let me know if this works