# Use custom aggregation with pyspark pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, group-by, aggregate

I have a **pyspark pandas** dataframe. I want to perform a custom aggregation using some predefined function, and for simplicity using numpy.nanmean
I get the following error "aggs must be a dict mapping from column name to aggregate functions (string or list of strings)"

I tried a minimum example like this in databricks

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import numpy as np

# Create a sample PySpark Pandas DataFrame
data = {'Category': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B'],
        'Value1': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
        'Value2': [100, np.nan, 300, 400, 500, 600]}  
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data))

# Convert PySpark DataFrame to PySpark Pandas DataFrame
pdf = ps.DataFrame(sdf)

# Group by 'Category' and apply nanmean_udf to 'Value2'
result = pdf.groupby('Category').agg(
    Sum_Value1=('Value1', 'sum'),
    Mean_val2=('Value2', np.nanmean)
)

print(result)
```

Note that I'm not talking about pandas dataframes but pyspark pandas so the pandas API on spark type.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: afaik, you need to make udf, `spark.udf.register('nanmean', np.nanmean)`  ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69732269/2956135

Comment: thanks, it appears that my question is a replicate of the one in the link. HOWEVER, it will still generate an error that is "Exception thrown in awaitResult: [INVALID_PANDAS_UDF_PLACEMENT] The group aggregate pandas UDF `NanMean` cannot be invoked together with as other, non-pandas aggregate functions."

That means, it is possible to register the udf and use it in the agg under two conditions 1) you do not use together with another pandas function (so only other udfs) 2) you must have a cluster without a Shared access mode (that's my other issue and is only applicable in databricks)